# How to pass the parameter to datetime picker function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datetimepicker, jquerydatetimepicker

As i had a datetimepicker function, and i need to iterate through an array which contains dates and then i need to add those dates with additional 15 minutes or 20 minutes based on some conditions,

what i need is , how to pass the array values(dates) to the datetimepicker and to add the minutes to that dates

previously my code was

```
 $(".addtime").datetimepicker({
 ignoreReadonly:true,
  format: 'LT',
  defaultDate: generateCurrentDate()+' 00:20'
});
```

as it adding for current date, i need to pass input as params and then i has to add to that , how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

string strdt = dateTimePicker1.Text;
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text);

you will have the selected Date in datetime format